# Retornar resultado de una consulta de oracle en Rust

Tags: sql, oracle, rust

He estado intentando usar oracle desde Rust con el siguiente driver [driver](https://github.com/kubo/rust-oracle), mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
use oracle::{Connection, ResultSet, Row};

pub struct Datos {
    cadena_conexion: String,
    user_id: String,
    password: String,
}

impl Datos {
    pub fn ejecutar_select(&mut self, consulta: String) -> Result<ResultSet<Row>, oracle::Error> {
        let conn = Connection::connect(self.user_id.clone(), self.password.clone(), "")?;
        let mut stmt = conn.statement(&consulta.clone()).build()?;
        let rows = stmt.query(&[])?;
        Ok(rows)
    }
}
```

Sin embargo la funcion `ejecutar_select` me muestra el siguiente error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `stmt`
  --> src\datos\database.rs:47:9
   |
46 |         let rows = stmt.query(&[])?;
   |                    --------------- `stmt` is borrowed here
47 |         Ok(rows)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `conn`
  --> src\datos\database.rs:47:9
   |
45 |         let mut stmt = conn.statement(&consulta.clone()).build()?;
   |                        --------------------------------- `conn` is borrowed here
46 |         let rows = stmt.query(&[])?;
47 |         Ok(rows)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

Intente retornar un puntero `Box<T>`, sin embargo tampoco funcionó, quisiera algo de ayuda para evitar que me de errores de punteros colgantes y poder retornar lo que realiza mi consulta

Nota: Borre mis constructores new, from y mis funciones ya que no me dejaba publicar la pregunta pero no estaban muy relacionados con la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solucion:

```
    pub fn ejecutar_select(&mut self, consulta: String) -> Result<Vec<Row>, oracle::Error> {
        let conn = Connection::connect(self.user_id.clone(), self.password.clone(), "")?;
        let mut stmt = conn.statement(&consulta.clone()).build()?; //Se transfiere la propiedad de conn a stmt
        let rows = stmt.query(&[]).unwrap(); //Se transifere la propiedad de stmt a rows
        let mut resultados = Vec::new(); // Se crea un objeto con propiedad transferible y que no se dropea al final de la funcion
        for row in rows {
            resultados.push(row?); // Se transfiere la propiedad de row a resultados
        }
        Ok(resultados) // La propiedad de resultados pertenecera a donde sea que se llame la funcion ejecutar_select
    }
```

Comment: Buenisimo!!! te tomas el trabajo tambien de explicarla, porfa??? gracias!!!